# how to get info about user visited statistics on azure static website?

Tags: azure, azure-static-website-hosting

I have a personal portfolio website that I have hosted on azure as an azure static website. Now I just wanted to know is there anyone visited my website or not. How can i do that. Thanks

Comment: `azure static website` --> You mean your website is hosted in Azure Storage. Right?

Comment: Yes, My website is hosted on Azure blog storage.

Answer (score 2):

> Now I just wanted to know is there anyone visited my website or not.
>   How can i do that.

There are two ways you can do that:

1. **Enable Application Insights**: You can enable Application Insights for your static web application hosted as a Single Page Application in Azure Storage. You can read more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript.
2. **View Storage Analytics Logs**: Though not a very user friendly way to see the activity performed on your static website, but you can view the storage analytics logs to view the operations performed on blobs (essentially the files) in `$web` blob container (your static website is hosted in this blob container. You can read more about storage analytics here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-analytics

Answer (score 0):

App Insights can not be enabled on Static Web Apps alone unless you have at least one function app deployed on your infra. The simplest solution to measure is to open a Google Analytics account and use a tracking ID on your web pages. It's almost realtime to see traffic details.